# Finding length of Longest Possible Palindrome

Tags: c#, algorithm, palindrome

I need to find the Maximum Length of a Palindrome In an Array of Words. I am able to find the length for 3-4 words but when it comes for some tricky words sequence, it fails. I have to extract 1st character of the words and pass to check for the maximum  length of Palindrome.

One of the Test Cases is below.

```
using System;
public class CandidateCode
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        //BBACCABB palindrom shoud return 7 
        //new string[] { "Bharti", "Bharat", "Akash", "Bhavya", "Chand", "Brijesh", "Chetak", "Arvind", "Bhavna" }));
        Console.WriteLine(FindMaxLengthPalindrome(new string[] { "Bharti", "Bharat", "Akash", "Bhavya", "Chand", "Brijesh", "Chetak", "Arvind", "Bhavna" }));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

//function to find Maximum Length Palindrom

    public static int FindMaxLengthPalindrome(string[]  input)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        for(int a=0;a<input.Length;a++)
        {
            s += input[a][0].ToString();
        }    
        string maxLengthPalindrome = "";    
        if (s == null) return s.Length;    
        int len = s.Length;    
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < len - i; j++)
            {
                bool found = true;
                for (int k = j; k < (len - j) / 2; k++)
                {
                    if (s[k] != s[len - (k - j + 1)])
                    {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }    
                if (found)
                {
                    if (len - j > maxLengthPalindrome.Length)
                        maxLengthPalindrome = s.Substring(j, len - j);
                }    
                if (maxLengthPalindrome.Length >= (len - (i + j)))
                    break;
            }    
            if (maxLengthPalindrome.Length >= (len - i))
                break;
        }    
        return maxLengthPalindrome.Length;
    }
}
```

By running the above code I get the answer 6, But It Should Return 7.
What Mistake am I doing here?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you intended for this code to do. If I see a function called `FindMaxLengthPalindrome` that takes an array of strings, I'd expect it to identify which (if any) of those strings is the longest palindrome and return its length. But that's not what this code is doing at all. Can you clarify your intent here?

Comment: Your check for palindromes does not work correctly - the first palindrome it identifies is `BCBCAB`.  Try splitting up your code into smaller pieces - one method to check for palindromes, one method to try all the substrings, and one method that extracts the substrings from the list of inputs.

Comment: Oops. there is something i am doing wrong. How to correct it. Actually my work is to find the largest palindrom string possible in a given string.

Comment: Try what I suggested - break your code into smaller pieces and step through it with the debugger to see what part is wrong.

Comment: I have tried doing that. But unable to identify the problem. Please help me out with a source code if possible

Comment: You do realize that your code is taking the first letter of each string in your string array and concatenating it into one string?  What about the rest of the letters?  Are you suppose to do this?  I would have thought that you have to check if any of these words are palindromes and find out which one is the largest palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
public static int PalindromeLengthPuzzle(string[] input1)
    {

        string firstChar = string.Empty;
        foreach (string str in input1)
        {
            firstChar = firstChar + str[0];
        }
        firstChar = getLongestPalindrome(firstChar);

        return firstChar.Length;

    }


    public static String getLongestPalindrome(String input)
    {
        int rightIndex = 0, leftIndex = 0;
        String currentPalindrome = "", longestPalindrome = "";
        for (int centerIndex = 1; centerIndex < input.Length - 1; centerIndex++)
        {
            leftIndex = centerIndex - 1; rightIndex = centerIndex + 1;
            while (leftIndex == 0 && rightIndex < input.Length)
            {
                if (input[leftIndex] != input[rightIndex])
                {
                    break;
                }
                currentPalindrome = input.Substring(leftIndex, rightIndex + 1);
                longestPalindrome = currentPalindrome.Length > longestPalindrome.Length ? currentPalindrome : longestPalindrome;
                leftIndex--; rightIndex++;
            }
        }
        return longestPalindrome;
    }
```